# SQL Server Express "Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I just created a Windows forms application with SQL Server 2008. I created the Setup File and installed the application.

When I click on any forms from the menu it shows an error

> a network related or instance specific error occurs.

And hence couldn't find the server and so.

I guess I have done something wrong in connection string

Here is my connection string

```
Dim constr As String = "Data Source= server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & Application.StartupPath & "\jshed.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The `User Instance` feature is **deprecated** and will be removed from a future version of SQL Server - please stop using it. See [this MSDN doc page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) for details

Comment: Connect Timeout=30 is wrong try Connection Timeout=30

Answer (score 0):

remove the following from the connection string

```
server=
```

try this

```
Dim constr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & Application.StartupPath & "\jshed.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
```

Comment: I removed "server=" Still its showing the same error.